# Android - Logging in to a php server

Tags: java, php, android

I'm currently trying to log in to a php server using HttpURLConnection. I have been successfully able to connect to the server/website as the response code I'm getting back is 200.

getPageContent has a response code of 200 while sendPost has a response code of 0. I am unsure about which getRequestProperty's are necessary and which aren't. I have looked at the elements and response and request headers and form data to get the correct information for the properties I did include however.

I can't really make too much sense of the string coming out of getPageContent as it is quite long but it does seem to be correct. getFormParams could possibly be outputting an incorrect string but information such as the username and password are included so I am unsure.

I'm stuck as to what's wrong or right in my attempt. Am I getting the form parameters correctly? And how do I send the login data correctly?

I call:

```
String page = getPageContent(URL);
String PostParams = getFormParams( page, "user", "pass" );
sendPost( URL, PostParams );
```

And the functions are:

```
private String getPageContent(String url) throws Exception {

        URL obj = new URL( url );
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        // default is GET
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

        conn.setUseCaches(false);

        conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", AGENT);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept",
                "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
        if (cookies != null) {
            for (String cookie : this.cookies) {
                conn.addRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie.split(";", 1)[0]);
            }
        }
        int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        MainActivity.globalV.responsecode = responseCode;

        BufferedReader in =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        // Get the response cookies
        setCookies(conn.getHeaderFields().get("Set-Cookie"));
        MainActivity.globalV.getPageContent = responseCode;

        return response.toString();
    }

    public String getFormParams(String html, String username, String password)
            throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

        Elements inputElements = doc.getElementsByTag("input");
        List<String> paramList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (Element inputElement : inputElements) {
            String key = inputElement.attr("name");
            String value = inputElement.attr("value");

            if (key.equals("user_username"))
                value = username;
            else if (key.equals("user_password"))
                value = password;
            paramList.add(key + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(value, "UTF-8"));
        }

//         build parameters list
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        for (String param : paramList) {
            if (result.length() == 0) {
                result.append(param);
            } else {
                result.append("&" + param);
            }
        }
        return result.toString();
    }

    private void sendPost(String url, String postParams) throws Exception {

        URL obj = new URL( url );
        HttpURLConnection conn = ( HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Host", "host website");
        conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", AGENT);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept",
                "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
        for (String cookie : this.cookies) {
            conn.addRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie.split(";", 1)[0]);
        }
        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Referer", "referer url");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/html");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(postParams.length()));

        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setDoInput(true);

        // Send post request
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(postParams);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        MainActivity.globalV.sendPost = conn.getResponseCode();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();
    }
```

Comment: And what exactly is your question?

Comment: How does one POST login details to a php server using HttpURLConnection? Since I got a response code of 200 from my first function, I know that the problem lies with one or both of my last two functions. Is my "getFormParams" function getting the parameters of the website correctly? Am I POSTing the login details in "sendPost" correctly?

Comment: I don't see anything obviously "wrong".  SUGGESTION: find a good way to observe the traffic going back and forth between your Android handset and your PHP server.  You need to see the actual HTTP requests and responses to discover who is "falling down", and correct the problem.  Here is one possibility: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

Comment: I used wireshark as I already had that installed. My app doesn't have any webviews so using chrome wasn't an option. I get MY IP DESTINATION IP HTTP 294 GET /login HTTP/1.1 followed by DESTINATION IP MY IP HTTP 1289 HTTP/1.1 200 OK  (text/html) and thats it. So it seems my app is able to get the okay that it established a connection but nothing else? The "get" request works fine but posting seems to be the issue here. If I were able to provide the necessary headers and html elements, would you be able to provide some insight possibly as to where I am going wrong?

Comment: The stream I am writing to my DataOutputStream are the parameters I'm getting from my "getFormParams" function. action=login&user_username=myuser&user_password=mypass&=Log+In is coming from the function and action=login&user_username=myuser&user_password=mypass is the source code from the form data of my php site. The only difference is the "&=Log+In" part at the end which is supposed to be the action of pressing the "Log In" button

Comment: I seriously recommend that you use newer libraries to do POST such as http://loopj.com/android-async-http/. Using this library you can post what you intended to post here in just less than 5 lines.